# How to get Memory Stream to output my soap formatter message

Tags: .net, web-services, serialization, exception

I wrote the following code, but the line `MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd)` didn't show anything? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I want to send an exception object to a web service for remote logging - is there a better method, (minimum amount of code, so I don't want to have to create a special transfer object that you copy the exception objct to and would like it a bit more flexible than .tostring)

```
    Dim sf As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter

    Try
        Integer.Parse("A")

    Catch ex As Exception

        Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
            sf.Serialize(ms, ex)

            Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(ms)
                MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd)
            End Using

        End Using
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the Position:

```
  sf.Serialize(ms, ex)
  ms.Position = 0
  using ...
```

Comment: That's annoyingly simple and makes sense... could you suggest another way of doing this? I seem to remember the memory stream being relatively expensive?

Comment: I think this (the MS) is about the most efficient way.

Comment: How about if I don't want all the soap information.. i.e. just the xml will do?

Comment: I don't think you can - I tried and it throws an exception - if it would serialise on it's own, I wouldn't need to do any of this :(